# Attribute table empty on a layer filled with data

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, excel

I have inserted some data from an .xls file and marked it on a map in ArcMap on a layer named "Kafichi"

[image: Mapped]

However when I right click on the layer and click on "Open Attribute Table" it gives me an empty table even though I have some data filled in.

[image]

Can anyone help?

I've tried exporting the data from the "Database$" however that did not work.

I can also assume that this is the same reason that when I do a Point Distance on those Coffee values with another layer it gives me an empty table.

Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Are you adding the data in through add xy data? Also some characters are not accepted in a field, making it null. Perhaps some formatting of the xls is messing it up, copy and paste the values only into a new xls or csv. Ensure that wgs84 is your projection when adding data also (if it is wgs84 later longs).